# Is the class diagram same thing as class model?

Tags: uml

I had been doing some UML class diagram examples from the recent exams for my software design course, and I found one where it says:"Design a **class model** for a specific problem, by using MVC and STATE pattern, but no need to include getters and setters." Is this the same thing as the regular class diagram? I've been googling and I found nothing UML based by searching for class MODEL.

Answer (score 3):

The model is abstract. A diagram is a view on the model. UML offers a number of different diagrams. There are mainly two categories: static and behavioral. Class diagrams fall under the static category and they show how the classes in the model are related to each other. You can create multiple class diagrams like one with all classes (assuming that you have a rather limited number of classes) and/or one per class with that in focus. Or you have sub-domains with related classes placed in one diagram. The behavioral diagrams shed light on how class instances communicate with each other at run time.

---

As a side note you can think of it in terms of [Platon's Cave Allegory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave). The diagrams are the shadows of the real world projected by a fire to the wall you can see from you chained position.

Comment: Great explanation, but I'm still confused. Could you give me an example of model and a diagram?

Comment: A model is what you find in a UML tool. Nobody can show you the abstract model since it's abstract. You can literally see only the diagrams. In a tool you can work with the abstract model, change it and to external readers most important: create diagrams from it which then build a part of the model. You probably need to try it yourself in an UML tool.

Comment: If "the diagrams are the shadows", then what is the model in this allegory? The real world? But I thought a model is an _abstraction_ of the real world, like shadows are a projection of the real world. I would say that the shadows are the model and each shadow is a diagram.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl It's an allegory of an allegory. Yes. The model would be the real world. Humans perceive models mainly visually (via diagrams). But the model is always more than the diagrams they see. The model "gods" show parts of their model (their world) to visitors but have a lot more in the background.

Answer (score 2):

"Design a class model" means: "Create one or more class diagrams that together form a consistent model".

A model in computer science is a graphical representation of (a piece of) software or of (a part of) the business domain in order to help people know or understand the subject the model represents (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_model)). This graphical representation may consist of one or more diagrams.

Comment: A  _model [...] is a graphical representation_ means they are identically which is not correct. You can create as many graphical representations of a model as you want without changing the model. But changing the model will change the parts shown in those graphics.

Comment: @qwerty_so : We define 'model' differently. There isn't any global authority that defines IT terminology, so it is hard to say who is right. When using a modeling tool, it may be helpful to make a distinction between the diagrams and the abstract 'underlying' model, as you do. But if you look at definitions like in wikipedia, this distinction is not made. UML defines model as follows: `A model captures a view of a physical system. It is an abstraction of the physical system, with a certain purpose.` I think `view` is equivalent to (graphical) representation.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia is also not an authority. Look into a dictionary and you find _a system or thing used as an example to follow or imitate_ or _a simplified description, especially a mathematical one, of a system or process, to assist calculations and predictions_